# Angular - How to make a File Upload Service?

Tags: angular, typescript, file

I find useful to use a service to upload images, however i'm unable to recover `url` value that is setted after `render.onload`.

```js
// service
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) {}

  uploadPhoto(event: Event) {
      const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];

      if (file.type === 'image/png' || file.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.type === 'image/jpg') {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          let url;
          reader.onload = () => {
              url = reader.result;
          };
          reader.onerror = (error: any) => {
              this.alertService.error(`Error ao carregar a imagem: ${error}`);
              return;
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          return { File: file, Url: url };
      } else {
          this.alertService.error('Formato inválido. Somente imagens do formato Png, Jpeg e Jpg são permitidos.');
          return;
      }
  }
}

// component
uploadBanner(event: Event) {
  const Upload = this.uploadService.uploadPhoto(event);
  if (Upload) {
    this.urlBanner = Upload.Url;
    this.shop.banner = Upload.File;
  }
}
```

How can I recover `url` and `file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating it as synchronous operation, but it isn't. You have to either use `Promise` or `Observable` to deal with this issue. And return a data when your onload event fires up.

```
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) {}

  uploadPhoto(event: Event): Promise<{file: any, url: string}> { {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];

      if (file.type === 'image/png' || file.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.type === 'image/jpg') {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        let url;
        reader.onload = () => {
          resolve({file, url: reader.result})
        };
        reader.onerror = (error: any) => {
          this.alertService.error(`Error ao carregar a imagem: ${error}`);
          reject(error)
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        let error = 'Formato inválido. Somente imagens do formato Png, Jpeg e Jpg são permitidos.'
        this.alertService.error(error);
        reject(error);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
// component
uploadBanner = async (event: Event) => {
  const url = await this.uploadService.uploadPhoto(event);
  console.log(url)
}
```

Comment: Got it. So in my component would be like this: `const Promise = this.uploadService.uploadPhoto(event);
      Promise.then((upload) => {
        this.urlBanner = upload.Url;
        this.shop.banner = upload.File;
      });
    }` ?

Comment: Thank you. Ive made a few async promises on Node.js/Express. Good to see that i can apply the same logic on Angular as well,

Comment: @James hope it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: just one more thing... how can I set types of the response `resolve({ File: file, Url: url });` to `{ File: File, Url: string }`? My component expects an empty json object here `const upload = await this.uploadService.uploadPhoto(event);`

Comment: this is `resolve`: `(parameter) resolve: (value?: {} | PromiseLike<{}>) => void`

Comment: @James Sorry, not sure, what you're asking.

Comment: lets say this is the resolve of the promise: `resolve({ file, url });`. when it arrives on my component, how to get `file` and `url` values separately?

Comment: @James well, you can then resolve like this `resolve({file, url: reader.result})`

Comment: yeah, but now its not an empty json anymore `{}`... this is tricking my `TSLint` to popup errors because my component expects `{}`

Comment: `uploadPhoto(event: Event): Promise<{file: any, url: string}> {` should suffice

Comment: what if i'm inside a loop of files `for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { reader.onload = () => {
          resolve({file, url: reader.result})
        }; }`. I need to resolve after all files have been rendered... is there a workaround around this?

Comment: then you have to maintain mutiple promise and return something like `Promise.all`

Comment: It doesn't work... after `reject()`, promise continues until it reaches `reader.onload = () => { resolve() }`

Comment: `reject()` stands for that only, promise completes as soon as you do `resolve`/`reject`